# C# regular expression for string of format

Tags: regex

Can someone provide me a regular expression for the below string

```
{"Name" : "TestName", "Street" : "TestStreet", "Place" : "TestPlace", "Country" : "TestCountry", "Type" : "TestType"}
```

Comment: [x] This is an exercise.

Comment: @alzaimar: what do you mean?

Comment: Regular expressions perform pattern matching on strings is order to validate them, extract substrings, etc. It's unclear what you are asking. What do you want this regex to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you provide is a JSON string, and JSON strings have cascading behavior and are thus **better not parsed using a regular expression**. You should use [`Json.Decode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg538324%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).

Only if **it is guaranteed** that the file will remain flat, you can parse this with a regex. But I **strongly advice against it**, it will eventually always fail, because people will eventually run it with non-flat JSON input. But here we go (don't say I didn't warned you):

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^\\s*\\{(\\s*,?\\s*\\\"([^\"]*)\\\"\\s*:\\s*\\\"([^\"]*)\\\")*\\}\\s*$");
```

You can then process the result using:

```
string json = "{\"Name\" : \"TestName\", \"Street\" : \"TestStreet\", \"Place\" : 
\"TestPlace\", \"Country\" : \"TestCountry\", \"Type\" : \"TestType\"}";

Dictionary<string,string> result = new Dictionary<string,string>();
Match m = regex.Match(json);
if(m.Success) {
    int captures = m.Groups[2].Captures.Count;
    for(int i = 0; i < captures; i++) {
        result.Add(m.Groups[2].Captures[i].Value,m.Groups[3].Captures[i].Value);
    }
}
```

The `result` is than a `Dictionary<string,string>` containing the keys and their corresponding values.

Comment: I am not supposed to use 3rd party libraries. :(

Comment: @DileepreddyJambula: this is not a third party library, it is part of the C# standard library. And furthermore I don't see why. Those libraries are way more reliable than parsing strings yourself (since most/all possible bugs are filtered out by now). You should **only** parse strings yourself if there are no better ways to do this.

Comment: I would be glad if you provided a regex.

Comment: @DileepreddyJambula: but you **can't** parse cascading content using a regex. Only if there is a **guarantee** that the data will be flat (no new `{}` or `[]` is opened as value), you can do this. Take also in account possible escaping and you get a way too complex regex. JSON is parsed by a *context-free grammar*.

Comment: @DileepreddyJambula: provided one, but as said before, you better don't use it.

Comment: Thanks CommuSoft, just one change in the string, It is Test_street and not TestStreet. Will the Regex provided work?

Comment: @DileepreddyJambula: the edit version will, but again, there is no regex (this can be **proven**) that can parse full JSON strings, only flat ones...